# Escape a space in a grep command inside a bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to do a simple grep like this inside a bash script,

```
grep "2017/01/01 00:" log.txt | wc -l
```

That works fine.

Inside my bash script I'm trying to do this,

```
i=16
DATE="$(date -d $2' '$i:00:00 '+%Y/%m/%d %H')"
echo $DATE
COUNT="$(grep $DATE $1 | wc -l)"
echo $COUNT
```

And I call it like this,

```
test.sh log.txt 2017/01/01
```

That fails because of the space, with a

```
: No such file or directory
```

So I tried adding double quotes, single quotes, and many other things, but they all fail...

```
COUNT="$(grep \"$DATE\" $1 | wc -l)"
```

I also tried using printf, and although this looks promising,

```
printf -v COMMAND "grep \"$DATE"
echo $COMMAND
# outputs: grep "2016/05/25 16
```

this one messes up with the beginning of the string!

```
printf -v COMMAND "grep \"$DATE\""
echo $COMMAND
# outputs: "rep "2016/05/25 16
```

What happened to the "g"??
How can I escape that space? I also tried replacing it by \s, which works in the command line, but gives wrong results from the bash script.

Really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a line-ending issue (!).  I tested your script on Cygwin, using vi as an editor.  With Windows line endings (`\r\n`), from `:set ff=dos`, I get

```
2017/01/01 16
: No such file or directory
```

But when I change the line endings to Unix (`\n`), with `:set ff=unix`, I get

```
2017/01/01 16
grep: 16: No such file or directory
```

which is not the same error message!  Other than that, you just need a bit more [quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=16
DATE="$(date -d "$2 $i:00:00" '+%Y/%m/%d %H')"
# Double-quote  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the whole argument rather than using ' '
echo $DATE
COUNT="$(grep "$DATE" "$1" | wc -l)"
# Double-quote^     ^ ^  ^ each individual variable you use
echo $COUNT
```

With a test file of

```
2017/01/01 16:15:00 flarp
2017/01/02 16:15:00 quux
2017/01/01 15:15:00 moby
```

I get the output:

```
2017/01/01 16
1
```

which I think is what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I was using cygwin, yes! I change the line endings of the file to LF only and now I get some results back with your code. However, I get different numbers (less entries) compared if I run the grep directly from the command line... It seems it's matching some different pattern :(

Comment: Nevermind. Instead of calling COUNT="$(grep ...)" directly i was calling a function that did the same and returned $COUNT, and calling it with countOccurrences $1 "$DATE" (the quotes so the space was passed in). That gives me less occurrences than calling the grep directly... I removed the function call and I'm doing it directly now. Thanks!